# How to check how many rabbitMQ consumers are currently available and running

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am using Java as the rabbitMq consumer for processing my input from the Node JS server. I am running 4 threads of same consumers on the Java to process 4 inputs parallel. If there was a 5th message received by the consumer it waits for current consumer process to complete and process the new one.

Is there a way to find how many consumers are currently in processing the inputs and how many consumers are currently waiting for the input?

Comment: Yes, however it would depend upon your specific scenario. Try looking at the management plugin.